# How to add trusted certs for org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient rather updating truststore at JVM level

Tags: java, ssl, wso2, rampart

I am currently working on an client program to access the soap webservice. The webservice is hit via WSO2 Identity Server (IS) Security Token Service (STS). I have coded using org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient. I am looking for a solution to add trusted certificates for STSClient rather than updating the trusted entries at JVM level, because post this webservice call, I have functionality which will need access to default cacerts. Kindly help me with the solution.

Basically I am trying to replace the below two lines

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystorePath);
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", keystorePwd);
```

I explored setting up stsClient.setCryptoInfo() with the truststore details, but I didn't get enough help from internet to understand what it does.

I tried exploring how set custom ssl for the stsclient, but couldn't figure out that also.

```
    public class Client {
        public void initialize() {
            try {
                loadConfigurations();

                    // set the trust store as a system property for communication over
                    // TLS.
                    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystorePath);
                    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", keystorePwd);

                    // create configuration context
                    ConfigurationContext configCtx = ConfigurationContextFactory
                            .createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(repoPath);

                    // create STS client
                    STSClient stsClient = new STSClient(configCtx);
                    stsClient.setRstTemplate(getRSTTemplate());

                    String action = null;
                    String responseTokenID = null;

                    action = TrustUtil.getActionValue(RahasConstants.VERSION_05_02,
                            RahasConstants.RST_ACTION_ISSUE);
                    stsClient.setAction(action);

                    // request the security token from STS.
                    Token responseToken;

                    Policy stsPolicy = loadPolicy(stsPolicyPath);

                    // add rampart config assertion to the ws-sec policies
                    RampartConfig rampartConfig = buildRampartConfig();
                    stsPolicy.addAssertion(rampartConfig);

                    responseToken = stsClient.requestSecurityToken(null, stsEPR, stsPolicy, relyingPartyEPR);

                    // store the obtained token in token store to be used in future
                    // communication.
                    TokenStorage store = TrustUtil.getTokenStore(configCtx);
                    responseTokenID = responseToken.getId();
                    store.add(responseToken);

                    // print token
                    System.out.println(responseToken.getToken().toString());

                    ...

                    //Send the token to relying party
                    if (enableRelyingParty) {
                        /* Invoke secured service using the obtained token */
                        OMElement responseElem = null;

                        // create service client
                        ServiceClient serClient = new ServiceClient(configCtx, null);

                        // engage modules
                        serClient.engageModule("addressing");
                        serClient.engageModule("rampart");

                        // load policy of secured service
                        Policy sec_policy = loadPolicy(relyingPartyPolicyPath);

                        // add rampart config to the ws-sec policies
                        sec_policy.addAssertion(rampartConfig);

                        // set in/out security policies in client opts
                        serClient.getOptions().setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY,
                                sec_policy);

                        // Set the token id as a property in the Axis2 client scope, so that
        // this will be picked up when creating the secure message to invoke
        // the endpoint.
                        serClient.getOptions().setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_CUSTOM_ISSUED_TOKEN,
                                responseTokenID);

                        // set action of the Hello Service to be invoked.
                        serClient.getOptions().setAction("urn:echoString");
                        serClient.getOptions().setTo(new EndpointReference(relyingPartyEPR));

                        // invoke the service
                        responseElem = serClient.sendReceive(getPayload(echoRequestMsg));
                        // cleanup transports
                        serClient.getOptions().setCallTransportCleanup(true);

                        System.out.println(responseElem.toString());

                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TrustException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private OMElement getRSTTemplate() throws TrustException {
                OMFactory omFac = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
                OMElement element = omFac.createOMElement(SP11Constants.REQUEST_SECURITY_TOKEN_TEMPLATE);

                if (ClientConstants.SAML_TOKEN_TYPE_20.equals(tokenType)) {
                    TrustUtil.createTokenTypeElement(RahasConstants.VERSION_05_02, element).setText(
                            RahasConstants.TOK_TYPE_SAML_20);
                } else if (ClientConstants.SAML_TOKEN_TYPE_11.equals(tokenType)) {
                    TrustUtil.createTokenTypeElement(RahasConstants.VERSION_05_02, element).setText(
                            RahasConstants.TOK_TYPE_SAML_10);
                }

                if (ClientConstants.SUBJECT_CONFIRMATION_BEARER.equals(subjectConfirmationMethod)) {
                    TrustUtil.createKeyTypeElement(RahasConstants.VERSION_05_02, element,
                            RahasConstants.KEY_TYPE_BEARER);
                } else if (ClientConstants.SUBJECT_CONFIRMATION_HOLDER_OF_KEY
                        .equals(subjectConfirmationMethod)) {
                    TrustUtil.createKeyTypeElement(RahasConstants.VERSION_05_02, element,
                            RahasConstants.KEY_TYPE_SYMM_KEY);
                }

                // request claims in the token.
                OMElement claimElement = TrustUtil.createClaims(RahasConstants.VERSION_05_02, element,claimDialect);
                // Populate the <Claims/> element with the <ClaimType/> elements
                addClaimType(claimElement, claimUris);

                return element;
            }

            private void addClaimType(OMElement parent, String[] claimUris) {
                OMElement element = null;
                // For each and every claim uri, create an <ClaimType/> elem
                for (String attr : claimUris) {
                    element = parent.getOMFactory()
                            .createOMElement(
                                    new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity",
                                            "ClaimType", "wsid"), parent);
                    element.addAttribute(parent.getOMFactory().createOMAttribute("Uri", null, attr));
                }
            }

            private Policy loadPolicy(String policyPath) throws XMLStreamException, FileNotFoundException {
                StAXOMBuilder omBuilder = new StAXOMBuilder(policyPath);
                return PolicyEngine.getPolicy(omBuilder.getDocumentElement());
            }

            private RampartConfig buildRampartConfig() {
                RampartConfig rampartConfig = new RampartConfig();
                rampartConfig.setUser(username);
                rampartConfig.setEncryptionUser(encryptionUser);
                rampartConfig.setUserCertAlias(userCertAlias);
                rampartConfig.setPwCbClass(pwdCallbackClass);

                Properties cryptoProperties = new Properties();
                cryptoProperties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "JKS");
                cryptoProperties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", keystorePath);
                cryptoProperties
                        .put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", keystorePwd);

                CryptoConfig cryptoConfig = new CryptoConfig();
                cryptoConfig.setProvider("org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
                cryptoConfig.setProp(cryptoProperties);

                rampartConfig.setEncrCryptoConfig(cryptoConfig);
                rampartConfig.setSigCryptoConfig(cryptoConfig);

                return rampartConfig;
            }

            private OMElement getPayload(String value) {
                OMFactory factory = null;
                OMNamespace ns = null;
                OMElement elem = null;
                OMElement childElem = null;

                factory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
                ns = factory.createOMNamespace("http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org", "ns");
                elem = factory.createOMElement("echoString", ns);
                childElem = factory.createOMElement("in", null);
                childElem.setText(value);
                elem.addChild(childElem);

                return elem;
            }

            ...
        }
        PasswordCBHandler.java is used by the underlying Rampart module to get the password of the key alias which is used to sign the request.

        public class PasswordCBHandler implements CallbackHandler{

            ...

            public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

                readUsernamePasswordFromProperties();

                WSPasswordCallback pwcb = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
                String id = pwcb.getIdentifier();
                int usage = pwcb.getUsage();

                if (usage == WSPasswordCallback.USERNAME_TOKEN) {

                   if (username.equals(id)) {
                       pwcb.setPassword(password);
                   }
                } else if (usage == WSPasswordCallback.SIGNATURE || usage == WSPasswordCallback.DECRYPT) {

                    if (keyAlias.equals(id)) {
                        pwcb.setPassword(keyPassword);
                    }
                }
          }

            ...
        }
```